# Adding more attributes to json

Tags: python, json

Currently, I store just the device_id of a certain object with an assigned sACN universe. The function looks like this:

```
for device_index in range(device_count):
    device_name = sdk.get_device_info(device_index)
    device_type = device_name.type
    if device_name.id not in conf:
        universe = get_free_universe()
        conf.update({device_name.id: universe}) 
        print(f"conf= {conf}")
    else:
        universe = conf[device_name.id] #main.py line 368
    save_config(DEVICE_PATH)
```

Which produces this JSON:

```
{
    "3192efa109cfb5d86f09a82a7cc00c5d": 4,
    "42aa42a0bb5fcee780fb1be13dfcb873": 5,
    "4b80e1817076307b36c58c31118f6696": 1,
    "62c13e2db726382e9c66d9f69020ab5e": 6,
    "a51da6fe155f299a3fc474c22310cde9": 2,
    "b5ff59af43d6c3572a41d7693b5bec1c": 3
}
```

Now I wanna store together with the device_id not only the universe, but its device_name.model attribute, kinda in this format:

```
{
  "3192efa109cfb5d86f09a82a7cc00c5d":
     "universe": 4,
     "model": "Vengance RGB PRO"
  "42aa42a0bb5fcee780fb1be13dfcb873":
     "universe": 5,
     "model": "M65 PRO"
}
```

I have absolutely no clue how to do it, afaik my conf is a python dict where I cant do something like this and I need to use python lists. I define it like this: `conf = load_config(DEVICE_PATH)`, the function `load_config()`looks like this:

```
def load_config(config_path):
    if not os.path.isfile(config_path):  #Create the file if not present
        open(config_path, "w+")
    if config_path == MQTT_PATH:
         with open(config_path) as f:  #load the config file
            try:
                return json.load(f)
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                data = {}
                data['enable_MQTT'] = True
                data['ip'] =""
                data['port']= 1883
                data['username'] =""
                data['password'] =""
                data['base_topic'] =""
                with open(config_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:  # Save config
                    json.dump(
                        data,
                        f, 
                        ensure_ascii=False,
                        sort_keys=False,
                        indent=4
                        )
                print(f"MQTT Config Created, please edit {MQTT_PATH} and restart this program!")
                print("For Home Assistant Auto Discovery, set base_topic to homeassistant!")
                sys.exit()
                
    with open(config_path) as f:  #load the config file
        try:
            return json.load(f)
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return {}
```

When I try to convert the list via `conf = list(conf)`, i just get the runtime error

```
  File "c:\Users\tenn0\Documents\Projects\iCue2sACN-mqtt\src\main.py", line 368, in <module>
    universe = conf[device_name.id] 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Ive marked in the first snipped the correct line

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, i can simply do a dict inside a dict. `conf.update({device_name.id: {"model": device_name.model, "universe": universe}})`  did the trick for me.

Comment: "kinda in this format" Okay, so you want to use a `dict` for each of the values that correspond to the `device_name.id` keys? Then *do that*. The fact that you are using JSON has no bearing on the problem; manipulate nested list/dict structures the same way you would normally.

Comment: You don't need lists.  You have a dict.  The value of each dict is a number, and you just need to replace that with another dict.

Comment: "afaik my conf is a python dict where I cant do something like this and I need to use python lists" I have very little idea what you think "something like this" is, no idea why you think you can't do it with dicts, and even less idea why you think using a list instead will make the problem easier. The entire point of your data is that you are *mapping from* the device IDs to information about the devices. That's what dicts *are*.

Comment: But as a heads-up, applying `list` to an existing dict gives you a list *of the keys*.